# how to update sql tabel with xml data in sql server 2008 using stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

My table looks like

**LANGUAGE ID**

```
(Primary Key)HOSPITAL ID LANGUAGE ID
```

And following is the insert query.

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[HOSPITAL_SPOKEN_LANGUAGE] 
(HOSPITAL ID, LANGUAGE ID)SELECT hospitalid,LanguageId 
FROM OPENXML(@XmlHandleLANGUAGE,'/ArrayOfSpokenLanuageInfo/SpokenLanuageInfo',2)
WITH ( LanguageId INT,hospitalid INT )
```

---

Below is the XML that I have.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?> <ArrayOfSpokenLanuageInfo
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">   <SpokenLanuageInfo>
       <LanguageId>8</LanguageId>
       <hospitalid>19</hospitalid>   </SpokenLanuageInfo>   <SpokenLanuageInfo>
       <LanguageId>13</LanguageId>
       <hospitalid>19</hospitalid>   </SpokenLanuageInfo>   <SpokenLanuageInfo>
       <LanguageId>26</LanguageId>
       <hospitalid>2</hospitalid>   </SpokenLanuageInfo>   <SpokenLanuageInfo>
       <LanguageId>52</LanguageId>
       <hospitalid>2</hospitalid>   </SpokenLanuageInfo> </ArrayOfSpokenLanuageInfo>
```

i want insert new items into table from XML ,existing items update table From XML .

Comment: You really should edit your post : use formatting, add more specific tags, be more precise about your problem... You won't get any response that way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #temp

DECLARE @xml xml
Set @xml= N'
 <ArrayOfSpokenLanuageInfo>
 <SpokenLanuageInfo>
       <LanguageId>8</LanguageId>
       <hospitalid>19</hospitalid>   
</SpokenLanuageInfo>   
<SpokenLanuageInfo>
       <LanguageId>13</LanguageId>
       <hospitalid>19</hospitalid>   
</SpokenLanuageInfo>    
</ArrayOfSpokenLanuageInfo>'

SELECT
 doc.col.value('LanguageId[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') LanguageId
,doc.col.value('hospitalid[1]', 'nvarchar(100)') hospitalid into #t
FROM @xml.nodes('/ArrayOfSpokenLanuageInfo/SpokenLanuageInfo') doc(col) 

insert into [dbo].[HOSPITAL_SPOKEN_LANGUAGE] ([LANGUAGE ID],[HOSPITAL ID]) (select * from #t)
```

Comment: Don't worry, it will insert data into your table HOSPITAL_SPOKEN_LANGUAGE

Comment: i want insert new items into table from XML ,existing items should be update into table From XML

Comment: This will insert new items.. it will not update the existing ones ;\

Comment: Update functionality only pending .can u help me

Comment: what do you mean by update? One of the column should not be updatable.. or can you update both columns?

Comment: see already  HOSPITAL_SPOKEN_LANGUAGE LanguageId 8,13  is there ok .if next time insert LanguageId  89,5,13  is there my XML so 2nd time LanguageId  89,5 only insert  into HOSPITAL_SPOKEN_LANGUAGE  .13 update into HOSPITAL_SPOKEN_LANGUAGE